# How to import from excel and save to database with Foreign Key using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these models:

**COUNTRIES**

```
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }
```

**STATES**

```
public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

**CITIES**

```
public int CITY_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string CITY_NAME { get; set; }
```

I already have data in `COUNTRIES` and `STATES`. But I want to import into `CITIES`. While importing, I want it to relate the `COUNTRY_ID` in `CITIES` to `COUNTRY_NAME` in `COUNTRIES`, and also `STATE_ID` in `CITIES` with `STATE_NAME` in `STATES`. Whereby it will save the int and not string into `CITIES`.

The data in Excel are in strings

Import controller:

```
public ActionResult ImportCitiesExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    var bodsList = new List<CITIES>();

    if (FileUpload != null)
    { 
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];

        if (true)//FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            string message = "";

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
            {
                var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                // if(currentSheet.Count)
                var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                {
                    var bod = new CITIES();
                    bod.CITY_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Text;
                    bod.CITY_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Text;
                    bod.COUNTRY_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Text;
                    bod.STATE_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Text;
                    bodsList.Add(bod);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //alert message for invalid file format  
            data.Add("<ul>");
            data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        data.Add("<ul>");

        if (FileUpload == null) 
            data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");

        data.Add("</ul>");
        data.ToArray();

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

[image: SAMPLE EXCEL]

But, when I export it should display `COUNTRY_NAME` not `COUNTRY_ID`, `STATE_NAME` not `STATE_ID`

Export controller:

```
public void CityToExcel()
{
    IEnumerable<CITIES> cities = _cacService.GetCacs();
    ExcelPackage ePackage = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet eWorksheet = ePackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reports");

    eWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Report";
    eWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "CITIES";

    eWorksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Date";
    eWorksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy} at {0:H: mm tt}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

    eWorksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "CITY_NAME";
    eWorksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "COUNTRY_NAME";
    eWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = "STATE_NAME";

    int rowStart = 5;

    foreach (var item in cities)
    {
        eWorksheet.Cells["A4:J4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        eWorksheet.Cells["A4:J4"].Style.Font.UnderLine = true;

        eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.CITY_NAME;
        eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.COUNTRY_NAME;
        eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.STATE_NAME;

        eWorksheet.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
        rowStart++;
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "CITIESReport.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(ePackage.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

How do I achieve this please?

Comment: What is your Data access approach ? Are you using EF ?

Answer (score 0):

Your table stores state id and country id for each city entity. So you need to derive the id of state and country name which you get when you parse your excel sheet.

To get the Id's from Name, you should read the available states and countries and states and store it in a dictionary where the name will be the key of the dictionary. This allows you to get the Id with **O(1)** lookup.

For example, if you are using EF as your data access technology, You can use the `ToDictionary` extension method to generate your lookup dictionary.

```
var countryDict = db.Countries.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, v => v.Id);
var statesDict = db.States.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, v => v.Id);

for (//yourForLoopToIterateOverExcelRowsGoesHere)
{
  var countryName = "Ghana"; // replace this with value from the row
  var stateName = "Accra"; // replace this with value from the row


if (countryDict.TryGetValue(countryName, out int countryId) &&
                                      statesDict.TryGetValue(stateName, out int stateId))
{
   // you can use countryId and stateId for saving now.
}
else
{
    //ignore this row /throw an exception
}
```

> But, when I export it should Display COUNTRY_NAME and not COUNTRY_ID,
>   STATE_NAME and not STATE_ID

All you have to do is JOIN the 3 tables/data sets and get the names from country and state table (Same as how you do a SQL join to get similar data).